# -ing after helping verbs such as "might"?

Tags: modal-verbs

Is it grammatically correct to use a verb with -ing after an helping verb like "might" like so?

"It might make people feeling bad".

If it's not, is it a rule which applies to all of the helping verbs?

Comment: Your example isn't a good one for using _ing_ after might. _Feel_ is in simple form because of _make_ not _might_. If you'd like to use _ing_ after might, you need to use a form of _be_ as in _he might be watching TV_.

Comment: @Yuri Note however that in your example, too, *might* does not govern the *-ing* form *watching*. It governs the infinitive *be*, and that in turn governs the *-ing* form -- in this case using *be* to form a progressive construction rather than a passive construction.

Comment: What do you mean by governing ?

Comment: @StoneB That's correct though easier to understand as a rule of thumb.

Comment: @GforOevOerD _governing_ in easy language is the _jurisdiction_ of a word over other words around it ;) _feel_ is governed by _make_ means it's under the influence of _make_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The modal verbs *can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would* always take unmarked infinitive verbforms—that is, infinitives without *to* markers—as complements, never any other form.

In your example, however, the verb which the modal governs is not *feel* but *make*, which is correctly cast in infinitive form.

*Feel* is governed by *make*; and this use of *make* meaning *cause* or *compel* also takes an unmarked infinitive verbform as its complement. You must therefore say

> ... make somebody **feel** bad.

Comment: Although in the passive *make* takes a *to*-infinitive instead: *I was made to feel bad.*

Comment: @snailplane A salutary reminder that English is like WW: "Do I contradict myself?
Very well then I contradict myself,
(I am large, I contain multitudes.)"

Comment: @StoneyB: you can't expect readers of this site to know that WW means Walt Whitman!

Comment: @TonyK At least two of them do.

Comment: @TonyK: It's not a problem. Even as a native speaker honours graduate in English I didn't recognise the Whitman quote, but googling just the first 4 words easily fills that potential gap in my knowledge. And we know that almost *every* user viewing this page has the wherewithal to do that search themselves just as easily as me. By tomorrow, I might have forgotten this attribution anyway, since I know I can easily retrieve it whenever I might need to in the years (*decades*, I'd like to hope! :) to come.